# How can I either end the program, or start the program over in a Visual basic console application, based upon user input?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I have a procedure at the end of my console application that ask the user to either hit enter to end the program, or type s to perform another search. The issue I'm having is no matter what the user types in the program end. What I would like to happen is if the user types s, then the program starts over and lets the user perform another search. The program is procedural and I need to find a way to start back off at the top of the program which ask the user to type a name to search. How can I accomplish this?

Here's the procedure that I'm having trouble with:

```
Private Sub terminateProgram()
    Console.Write("Press the enter key to end the program or press s to search again")
    If (CStr(Console.ReadLine()) = "s") Then
        Console.WriteLine("It worked")
    Else
        Console.Read()
    End If
```

Note: As you can see, I'm just writing "It worked" to the window just to at least try and capture the "s" being entered.

Answer (score 1):

Structure your program in a loop and your method to return a boolean, so that as long as your method returns "False" the program keeps running:

```
Sub Main()
   Do

   Loop While Not terminateProgram()
End Sub

Public Function terminateProgram() As Boolean
    Console.Write("Press the s key to search again or any other key to end the program")
    Return Console.ReadKey(True).KeyChar.ToLower() <> "s" 
End Function
```